# HTTP_REFERER & REMOTE_ADDR Combined

Tags: php, wordpress

Have a little issue that i hope someone can help me out with. I have a  WordPress website that i only want to grant employee's access to. So I'd like to use a HTTP Referer so that way i can add a link from our intranet site, kind of like this...

```
if (strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"],'intranetsite.com') == true) 
   {     
 echo "/";
   }
else
   {
 header( 'Location: http://wordpress.com/wp-admin' ) ;
   }
```

However i would also like to add a list of trusted ip addresses, using the following code...

```
$allowlist = array(
    '00.0.000.000',
    '00.00.0.000',
);

if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$allowlist)){
    header('Location: http://wordpress.com/wp-admin');
}
```

What would be the easiest way to combine this code? Or is there a better way i should be doing this?

Hope this all makes sense, if not let me know if i need to clarify on anything.

Apologize for my lack of coding ability, still learning the ropes. Any help at all would be great appreciated.

Comment: Tried using `&&` (and) in your if-statement? `if (strops(...) == true && in_array(...))`.

Comment: Any response? Don't just leave the questions hanging (like you did with your last question from March). If an answer helped, mark it as correct. If it didn't, let us know.

Comment: Sorry, my apologies on that, didn't mean to leave that in limbo. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a security standpoint, the referrer is an unreliable means of restricting access to a website. It can be forged and not all browsers send it correctly.

If you want a more secure and unified way of restricting access to your website, consider using Apache's .htaccess file placed in the root of the website.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthUserFile /var/www/your_path/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from <your first IP>
allow from <your second IP>
allow from <your third IP>
...
```

The first section with the Auth directives have you specify an .htpasswd file which will contain the usernames and encrypted passwords which your users will authenticate against when accessing the website. There are multiple ways to create this file, but the easiest way is to do it online using a tool like [this one](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/).

The second section specifies that connections will be denied from all IPs with the exception of those listed by you with the help of the *allow* directive.

Comment: I figured going the .htaccess route would probably be a better way going about this. Thanks for the suggestion and the code example, I'll give it a try.